# How to get two foreach into one foreach loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have two variables that contains last names and first names: `$fnames` and `$lnames`, and I'm looking to display first names and then last names but it doesn't work

My two variables contain MySQL function's to get names from the database

Here is my code:

```
function select($row, $arr) {
    global $bdd;
    $test = $bdd - > prepare("SELECT ".$row." FROM ".$arr);
    $test - > execute();
    return $test - > fetchAll();
}

$lnames = select("lnames", "people WHERE lnames LIKE '$query%'");
$fnames = select("fnames", "people WHERE fnames LIKE '$query%'");

foreach($fnames as $fname AND $lnames as $lname) {
    echo $fname[0].$lname[0]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: you have two variable of type `array` or something else . please clear your question

Comment: provide more details

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi added more details

Comment: share definition for `select` method ?

Comment: your `select` method is not generic, update and make more separated part for `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine both where in one query, to get `fnames` and `lnames` always together

```
$rows = select("`fnames`,`lnames`", "people WHERE `lnames` LIKE '$query%' OR fnames LIKE '$query%'");

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['fnames'] . $row['lnames'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one array to loop through and use the loop's index to access the 2nd array's values like this:

```
foreach ($fnames as $k => $v) {
    echo $fnames[$k] . $lnames[$k] . "<br>";
}
```

**NOTE: This will only work if both the arrays are having same numbers of elements in them.**

Comment: what if any user don't have `last name`

Comment: It outputs "Array Array"

Comment: @Er.AmitJoshi, Dylan has to query the DB in such a way that for empty last names, it returns empty string so the numbers of array members remains the same and the sequence of the first name and last name in each of them remains the same. So when we print using one loop, correct fname and lname gets appended.

Comment: In this case fnames and lnames can be of different name,because both are not bounded together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop one and use the key on the other.

```
foreach ($fnames as $key => $fname) {
    echo $fname . $lnames[$key] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: In this case fnames and lnames can be of different name,because both are not bounded together.

Comment: @C2486 I believe OP knows what the output is from his DB. If the names was unordered in the arrays OP should have mentioned it in the question. And there is no reason why the DB should return the results in a different order.

Comment: suppose your name is `Andreas Pereira` and you search for `Andreas` then you will not get `Pereira`. because there is no `Andreas` in surname section , rather it would be like `Andreas` in `fnames or lnames` and get `fnames or lnames`. I hope you understand as I suggest in my answer

Comment: @C2486 yes I understand it, but you ASSUME that is the case. Big difference! Let OP tell what it really is and then post from there.